# Responsive HTML 5 canvas overlaps body content

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I am having trouble getting my HTML 5 canvas to stop overlapping my body content when I scale to varying browser sizes. I am new to front end development so any help would be greatly appreciated. Site is: http://www.alanhurt.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a width and height to the `canvas#triangle-lost-in-space` target.

So in your CSS add these lines:

```
canvas#triangle-lost-in-space {
    width  : 100%;
    height : 850px;
}
```

This will work until your first media break point at 767px. To fix it after the breakpoint add:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    canvas#triangle-lost-in-space {
        height : 600px;
    }
}
```

This was done via the chrome inspector - so just make sure when implementing to have those changes at the bottom of your stylesheet so they will be applied and not overwritten.

Comment: Hi Schybo. I tried the above but it didn't seem to correct the issue. Thank you for taking the time to come up with a solution.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunate it didn't turn out - I'll look into it, but if it's working like that from the inspector I'm not sure I'll be able to diagnose why it's not working on your website.